# problema con el input type file en react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input-type

tengo un inconveniente que ya no se como solucionar y espero puedan ayudarme por favor. 
Tengo un componente input de tipo file que no está capturando valor.

**Este es mi componente input:**

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
    fileRef.current?.click();
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid place-items-center w-full mt-4 px-3">
      <button
        className="cursor-pointer rounded-lg w-full bg-white hover:bg-cyan-color text-cyan-color font-semibold uppercase hover:text-white py-2 px-4 h-12 border border-cyan-color"
        onClick={onClickHandler}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
          <FiUpload className="hover:text-white" /> &nbsp; Subir tu cv
        </div>
      </button>
      <input
        accept="application/pdf"
        ref={fileRef}
        type="file"
        name="resume"
        id="resume"
        hidden
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Y estoy haciendo el llamado en otro componente que es un formulario:

```
const resume = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

<form action="" onSubmit={onSubmit} className="w-8/12 bg-white p-2">
   <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-5">
     <File fileRef={resume} />
   </div>
   <Submit name={t("submit_button.name")} width="w-full" />
</form>
```

y el resultado que me muestra después del submit es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal o que estoy dejando pasar porque no captura el documento seleccionado.